# Return two JSON objects From WEB API in same call SQL 2016

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-web-api, sql-server-2016

I'm using AXIOS in a Vue application that calls a .NET WEB API.  So client side is JavaScript in a Vue.js page. All of my calls so far call one JSON object.  Below is my simplified code.

```
Declare @json nvarchar(max)

    Set @json = (SELECT TOP 1 MemberID FROM AA_ADMIN_API_Pubs_Members WHERE [MemberID] = 1223
    ORDER BY PMID desc
    FOR JSON AUTO)

    Declare @json2 nvarchar(max)

    Set @json2 = (SELECT TOP 1 PMID FROM AA_ADMIN_API_Pubs_Members WHERE [MemberID] = 1223
    ORDER BY PMID desc
    FOR JSON AUTO)



SELECT @json
SELECT @json2
```

Returns:

```
[{"MemberID":1223}]
```

and

```
[{"PMID":31098295}]
```

What I would like is a way to combine the two JSON objects so I can parse it on the client side without having to go back and make another call.

I thought about passing one object like

```
SELECT @json + ';' + @json2
```

and then splitting and parsing

[{"MemberID":1223}];[{"PMID":31098295}]

But of course it's not a valid JSON object.  Is there a standard way of passing the data?  Thanks

Comment: Use `out`parameters and return only Ids, serialize JSON at code site

Comment: Can you add a little more detail?  I'm not sure I understand what you are saying.

Comment: In your Web API code, map the two results into an instance of a class that you've created to represent your data.

Comment: I understand that I can send all of the resultssets to the Web API and then built my JSON using Newtonsoft JSON or even just serialize the class.  That's exactly the way I did it with MS 2014.   But I would like to  use the the built in JSON functions of MS 2016 if possible.